# How to convert string to component for reading value

Tags: java, swing, components, textfield

Currently I have this method ofcode it take in the variable name of the textfield and read what has been entered

```
public Object getValue(Component c) {

          Object val = null;

          if (c instanceof CustomWizardComponent) {
             val = ((CustomWizardComponent) c).getValue();
          } else if (c instanceof JTextComponent) {
             val = ((JTextComponent) c).getText();
          } else if (c instanceof AbstractButton){
             val = ((AbstractButton) c).isSelected();
          } else if (c instanceof JComboBox){
             val = ((JComboBox) c).getSelectedItem();
          } else if (c instanceof JList){
             val = ((JList) c).getSelectedValues();
          } else {
             log.warn("Unknown component: "+c);
          }

          return val;
       }


 JTextField text = new JTextField();
 text.setName("text");
 add(text);
 System.out.print("The component value is  "+ page.getValue(text));
```

Now I have set the name to have the same name as the JTextField component name. How can I convert that string to component to read the same field? My ideal new method should be able to take in String and then convert to component and get the value

```
 public String getValue(String item)
    {
        Component c=item;
          Object val = null;

      if (c instanceof CustomWizardComponent) {
         val = ((CustomWizardComponent) c).getValue();
      } else if (c instanceof JTextComponent) {
         val = ((JTextComponent) c).getText();
      } else if (c instanceof AbstractButton){
         val = ((AbstractButton) c).isSelected();
      } else if (c instanceof JComboBox){
         val = ((JComboBox) c).getSelectedItem();
      } else if (c instanceof JList){
         val = ((JList) c).getSelectedValues();
      } else {
         log.warn("Unknown component: "+c);
      }
      return val.toString();
     }

 JTextField textstring = new JTextField();
 text.setName("textstring");
 add(text);
 System.out.print("The component value is  "+ page.getValue("textstring"));
```

Comment: How are `String` and `Component` related?

Comment: @MadProgrammer the string and the component will be the same for the name and the JTextField. I have edited my question on the second part please take a look.

Comment: using the given name, you should be able to search your actual component (if one to one relation)

Comment: DYM 'name' as in [`Component.setName(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29)?  Naming components that way for later use, is typically considered a sign of bad design.  It is probably better to use a `Map` of some sort, or any of a number of other strategies, depending on exactly what it is, that this is intended to achieve.

Comment: @wxyz but how do I make my getValue method take in string now?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson do u mean  page.getValue(Component.setName("textstring")) ? This doesnt work

Comment: *"This doesnt work"*   Are you sure you are cut out for programming?

Answer (score 1):

Empirically, you can use `Component#setName()` and maintain a [`Map<String, Component>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) that would let you look up a `Component` by name using the `String` returned by `Component#getName()` as the key.

Theoretically, you might want to look at a higher level of abstraction, such as might be provided by a [wizard framework](http://www.google.com/#q=java%20wizard%20framework).